Rancher Desktop on windows: When trying to use maven to build and run java service I get localhost:2375 connection refused
I was using docker Desktop but moved to rancher, I dont see an option to expose port 2375 on rancher.
Now I am running into the issue where it keeps saying the connection is refused.
org.mandas.docker.client.exceptions.DockerException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
The same setup works on Mac but errors on windows.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the rancher desktop and all the setup that I did for mac. but still unable to get it to work.

Making the Docker socket available on a TCP port is a major security exposure.  What tool are you using that can't use the standard Unix socket (or the Windows equivalent)?  Can you [edit] the question to include the enough of source code you're working with to demonstrate the issue?

Localhost is not what you expect inside a container.
